# Ubuntu 11.04 apt-get install libncurses5-dev no candidate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I am linux total newbie. I would like to install new packages but I am not able to do this with some:

I try

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
E: Package 'libncurses5-dev' has no installation candidate
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install kernel-package fakeroot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kernel-package is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kernel-package' has no installation candidate
```

Same problem for example with samba.
My Ubuntu version is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty

2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: ths question would be more suitable on askubuntu

Answer (score 0):

11.04 isn't supported anymore, you should really update at least to the next supporetd LTS version (12.04).

Otherwise you'd need to update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com instead of the repository currently used, as the default ubuntu sources and mirrors don't contain the packages for 11.04 anymore.